# Default buttons don't show outline styles on click

Tags: html, css

Why do the default buttons don't show any outline styles on click but the custom button shows a outline style on click?

How do I remove the outline styles from a custom button on click but keep the outline styles when the users uses the keyboard to navigate to it (same behavior like the default buttons)?

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background: cyan;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button">Why no outline styles on click?</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 24px">
    <button class="btn">Why outline styles on click?</button>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I can't use outline: none for accessibility reasons. Refer: http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: You can fix this with JS using `blur`. I'm guessing that the user agent is responding to browser events and is removing the focus for default styled elements and not for custom styled elements (at least for certain properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about accessibility, then why do you want to remove the outline?? It would be perfectly ok for accessibility by the way to remove the outline but add a different style: `background-color`, `color` or `border` for instance.

Comment: An example of this: in the SO snippets, the "run code snippet" and "copy snippet to answer" buttons and the "hide results" link get the `:hover` styles on `:focus`. Don't know enough about the WCAG to know if that style change is considered obvious enough (and the "expand snippet" link isn't tab-selectable!) but anyway that's one illustration

Answer (score 2):

Taken and edited from a previous question here:

[Why pseudo element :focus on button when using TAB but not click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046375/why-pseudo-element-focus-on-button-when-using-tab-but-not-click#)

You can do this via js

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

var tabbing = false;

window.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        tabbing = true;
    }
}

submit.onfocus = function (e) {
    if (tabbing) {
        this.classList.add("tabbed");
    }
};

submit.onblur = function () {
    this.classList.remove("tabbed");
    tabbing = false;
};
```

```css
#submit.tabbed:focus {
    outline: 2px solid green;
}

#submit{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background: cyan;
  border: none;
  }

#submit:focus{
  outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" />
<br>
<label>Pass:</label>
<input type="password" />
<br>
<label>Save Password:</label>
<input type="checkbox" />
<br>
<br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

This will show an outline only when a user has tabbed, not clicked the button.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use javascript to differentiate between `focus` that comes from a click and `focus` that comes from a keypress.

Check out the answers to

- [Determine what triggered focus event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727005/determine-what-triggered-focus-event)
- [Differentiate between focus event triggered by keyboard/mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653332/differentiate-between-focus-event-triggered-by-keyboard-mouse)
- [Detect focus initiated by tab key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144611/detect-focus-initiated-by-tab-key)

A bunch of good options there - assuming you're able to add js to this page, you'll find one that works for you

Comment: Though keep in mind that not every person who benefits from web accessibility will be navigating by keyboard. If you want this page to be accessible, the `:focus` should be shown in *some* way (see @wim-merten's answer). And careful if you're working under a web accessibility policy: it's possible that not showing the `:focus` would be a policy violation

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `outline` attribute of the button while focused using `:focus {outline: none;}`

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background: cyan;
  border: none;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button">Why no outline styles on click?</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 24px">
    <button class="btn">Why outline styles on click?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant use outline none for accessibility reasons

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers set the following default,

```css
:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

and needs to be over ridden:

```css
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: cant use outline: none for accessibility reasons

Comment: You can't access your css?

Comment: @Okomikeruko removing the outline is a bad practice for accessibility reasons. Some users can't use a mouse and use a keyboard only. The outline lets them know what element has focus and can perform an action. Without an outline it's all a guess to those users what will happen when they tab and then hit _Enter_.

Comment: Then how about some JavaScript so the outline is only missing when clicked and not tabbed to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046375/why-pseudo-element-focus-on-button-when-using-tab-but-not-click

Answer (score 0):

You can remove outline by including:

```
.btn{
   outline: none;
}
```

Another thing that you need to know is:
When you use ex. `.btn:active` active means on action like clicking the button.

All you have to do is include outline by default and remove it on action or focus.

Comment: cant use outline: none for accessibility reasons

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by accessibility, but if you wan to remove the outline you need to use

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

[fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qnxe7qrd/)

I don't think there is a way to differentiate, `focus` on button by keyboard input or mouse click, both trigger the `focus` event of the button.

Comment: The focus remains on the custom button but not on the default styled button. OP wants to fix that. Your solution removes the focus when tabbing to the custom button.

Comment: "Web accessibility means that people with disabilities can use the Web. More specifically, Web accessibility means that people with disabilities can perceive, understand, navigate, and interact with the Web, and that they can contribute to the Web. Web accessibility also benefits others, including older people with changing abilities due to aging." More at https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php An important issue in general, and one that's on its way to becoming a part of more developers lives as more and more large institutions add web accessibility policies