# How to detect if a click() is a mouse click or triggered by some code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect if a click() is a mouse click or triggered by some code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `which` property of the event object. It should be `undefined` for code-triggered events:

```
$("#someElem").click(function(e) {
    if(e.which) {
        //Actually clicked
    }
    else {
        //Triggered by code
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/frw8j/) of the above.

**Update** based on comments

Pressing the Enter key when an `input` element has focus can trigger the `click` event. If you want to distinguish between code-triggered clicks and all other clicks (mouse or keyboard triggered) then the above method should work fine.

Comment: `which` can detect keyboard activity but OP want only mouse activity

Comment: How can an element be clicked by the keyboard?

Comment: You've never pressed enter to log in?

Comment: @awm - Pressing enter does not trigger the click event.

Comment: Are you sure?  If a button or checkbox has focus, the "enter" key will cause a click, as far as I know.

Comment: i think that the correct way is checking for e.originalEvent wich is undefined if the event is triggered programmatically (but maybe i'm wrong)

Comment: @james That depends.  Pressing enter when you're focused on an input field simply does a submit.  Pressing enter when you're focused on a button clicks the button.  Conceded, logging in is not the best example.

Comment: @James Allardice, `click` events can be triggered by various different devices to support user accessibility. If you tab through a page, you can use the `enter` key to trigger a `click` event on links and form controls. It is unfortunate how many developers never take the time to consider users with disabilities or who may be using screen readers to browse the internet.

Comment: I stand corrected. When an input element has focus, pressing enter can trigger the click event. You learn something new every day :) However, for the OPs case I think the solution in my answer should still suffice - programattic "clicks" will still be distinguishable.

Comment: @JamesAllardice This doesn't work in IE8. `e.which` is `0` (zero) when you manually click...

Comment: @James as i stated maybe then it's more correct to check if originalEvent is undefined.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Could you back up your solution with a source which confirms that mouse events contain a `which` property? According to MDN the `e.which` property is defined for keyboard events, not mouse events, and also it's deprecated and should be avoided (and it's non-standard - not part of the DOM Events model).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - No, my source was just what I've used in the past. No idea where it came from originally! I'm very tempted to delete this answer. The answer by Nicola seems to be suitable. Although http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ states that all `event` objects will have a `which` property.

Comment: @James i'm pretty sure that e.which is not standard, i think jQuery normalizes that in it's event object

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti - Yeah, that's correct. That's what I meant by my last comment.

Comment: This doesn't work with $('#someElem')[0].click(); In that case, I think you'll have to check other values in the event (layerX, layerY, offsetX, offsetY, pageX, pageY, screenX, screenY).

Answer (score 14):

You should check e.originalEvent:

```
$("#someElem").click(function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent === undefined) {
        //triggered 
    }
    else {
        //clicked by user
    }
});
```

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/frw8j/3/

Comment: That seems to differentiate triggerHandler from not, but when I just did:
$("#someElem")[0].click()
It was treated as a real "click".

Answer (score 5):

Wait for some time and use `event.isTrusted` - its supported by IE9, Opera 12, and Firefox Nightly. Webkit will support it too, most probably.

Currently, there is no guaranteed way to know.

Comment: I don't agree: e.originalEvent does the trick

Comment: don't want to break your pink glasses, but jQuery is not a magic wand ...