# Detect if button click real user or triggered by a script

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Is there any method that enables me to detect whether a button click was performed by a real user and not some automated method (javascript) that a user has loaded onto their browser developer console or other browser developer tool?

I tried the following methods suggested in various stackoverflow posts but none of them appear to work. 
REF: [How to detect if a click() is a mouse click or triggered by some code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635274/how-to-detect-if-a-click-is-a-mouse-click-or-triggered-by-some-code)

Script Detection methods tried and failed:

```
mybutton.click(function (e) {
    if (!e.which) {
        //Triggered by code NOT Actually clicked
        alert(' e.which - not a real button click')
    } else if ('isTrusted' in e && !e.isTrsuted) {
        //Triggered by code NOT Actually clicked
        alert(' e.isTrusted - not a real button click')
    } else if (e.originalEvent === undefined) {
        //Triggered by code NOT Actually clicked
        alert(' e.originalEvent - not a realbutton click')
    }
    //                  else if (!e.focus) {
    //                      //triggered  // does not detect e.focus on a real btn click
    //                      alert(' e.focus - not a realbutton click')
    //                  }
    else {
        // Button hopefully clicked by a real user and not a script
    }
})
```

If I run the following script to trigger the button click from the Chrome browser console none of the methods above traps it as being triggered by a script.

```
var button = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
button.click();
```

==========================================================================

Thank you for all your responses and thanks to stackoverflow for providing such a great site that facilitates so much knowledge sharing and for saving us techies an untold number of hours.

It appears that I still do not have reliable method. All 3 browsers (FF, IE & Chrome) provide a developer/console interfaces for a user to run/inject a javascript on my webpage. It appears that each browser flavor traps some event property values a little differently. For example: Chrome traps the difference between a script activated cick and a real user with e.screenX but in IE: e.screenX has the same value for both a script click (synthetic) and a user button click

The following detection methods either did not work at all or are inconsistent across the different browsers: e.which e.isTrsuted e.originalEvent (event.source != window) (e.distance != null)

The mousedown event appears to be only triggered by a real user button click, but I have to assume there is some script method to emulate a mousedown in addition to a button click event

```
$(me.container + ' .mybutton').mousedown(function (e) { 
    alert('mouseisdown real button click'); 
}
```

If anyone can figure out a reliable method that works across multiple browsers, that detects the difference between a synthetic (script) button click and a button click by a user, you will deserve superhero status.

Comment: As of now, I can't see an accepted answer. And worse, not one that I would accept.

Comment: For firefox e.isTrusted works, don't know for others. **e.isTrsuted** doesn't work ;-)

Comment: This question was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 15):

when a button click happens through the mouse, the event e usually has the mouse pointer location recorded. Try something like :

```
   if(e.screenX && e.screenX != 0 && e.screenY && e.screenY != 0){
     alert("real button click");
   }
```

Comment: Works for Chrome but not in IE dev console. In IE e.screenX has +values for both manual and scripted button.click

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible in all cases.

As other answers mentioned, you can look for the mouse coordinates (clientX/Y and screenX/Y), and if they're not present, you can assume it was *probably* not a human-generated action.

But, if the user tabs onto the button and uses the space bar to click it, or otherwise clicks it without using a mouse, the coordinates will also be zero, and this method will incorrectly determine it to be a scripted click.

Also, if the script uses `dispatchEvent` instead of `click`, coordinates can be given to the event. In this case, this method will incorrectly identify it as a user-generated click.

```
// This will produce what appears to be a user-generated click.
function simulateClick(element) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 110, 111, 10, 11, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bYq7m/

Answer (score 5):

For security purposes when you trigger an event with javascript it will register differently than if the user triggered the event. Console log the `ev` object and you will see significant differences between the two cases.

```
mybutton.click(function(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
});
```

Here are some sample output of the two cases:

```
jQuery.Event
currentTarget: button
data: null
delegateTarget: button
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: true
jQuery191011352501437067986: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: null
result: undefined
target: button
timeStamp: 1360472753601
type: "mousedown"
__proto__: Object

jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "mousedown", isDefaultPrevented:     function, timeStamp: 1360472840714, jQuery191011352501437067986: true…}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
button: 0
buttons: undefined
cancelable: true
clientX: 39
clientY: 13
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: button
data: null
delegateTarget: button
eventPhase: 2
fromElement: null
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse() {
jQuery191011352501437067986: true
metaKey: false
offsetX: 37
offsetY: 11
originalEvent: MouseEvent
pageX: 39
pageY: 13
relatedTarget: null
screenX: 1354
screenY: 286
shiftKey: false
target: button
timeStamp: 1360472840714
toElement: button
type: "mousedown"
view: Window
which: 1
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: This is a drag example, the question states a question on click event.

Comment: In Chrome on the button.click event:  e shows (e.originalEvent.type == 'mousedown') for both a scripted click and a real click. Are there any other properties that will be different and consistent across different browsers?

Comment: How about [ev.isTrigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704168/in-javascript-what-is-event-istrigger)

Answer (score 4):

Use "event.isTrusted" to know event is triggered from Javascript or User click.

Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="myInput">
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="callFunction(event)">Click Me</button>

  <script>
    function callFunction(event) {
      console.log(event.isTrusted); // true only when user clicks 'Click Me' button
    }
    window.onload = function () {
      let event = new Event("click");
      callFunction(event); // false
    }
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click(); // false
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Event object have a `nativeEvent` object which contains `isTrusted` field.

Its value will be `false` when event is not triggered by real user.
So you can check if real user clicked the button by -

```
if(event.nativeEvent.isTrusted){
    //Real user
} else {
    //Triggered by script
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/332AA/) Here.

```
$("button").mousedown( function(e) {
    if(e.which) {
        alert(1);
    }
});
$("button").trigger("mousedown");
```

Or Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onmousedown = function(e) {
 if(e.which) {
    alert(1); // original click
 }
}
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onmousedown();
```

You can see in the fiddle, it will not let trigger function to call but only when mouse is down on button. If automated click is triggered on button then `e.which` is undefined which can be trapped easily.

**UPDATE :** [Fiddle For Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/332AA/3/)

Comment: Good fiddle, I just added a console.log to it so he can see that output like I described in my answer if he wanted. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/332AA/1/)

Comment: @KyleWeller You can also add it to my answer Sir.

Comment: The `e.which` trick is already mentioned in the question; and it seems to not work for OP.

Comment: @Jack I have tried many times the fiddle and its working fine. You can also check.

Comment: @AspiringAqib Have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();`?

Comment: @Jack you were right. But updated my answer. Instead of click event, use mousedown event.

Comment: @AspiringAqib How would this be useful? At best you've found a way of registering an event that doesn't fire when you call the click method on the element. This does not satisfy the requirements of the question. http://jsfiddle.net/sRf5H/6/

Comment: What if the user tabs onto the button and presses the space bar to "click" it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem adding data attribute to element, then check if this attribute is present ( means trigered by script) and remove the attribute

```
let element = document.getelementbyid('btn');
//set before triggering
element.setAttribute('data-triggered-by-script', '1');
element.click();
element.onClick(function(e){if (e.target.getAttribute('data-triggered-by-script' == 1){
//do when triggeted by script
e.target.setAttribute('data-triggered-by-script', '');
})})
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to detect if it's a legit user using your site, and not a third party injected script / bot

Answer (score 0):

For me it works this way:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.onclick = function(event)
{       
    if (event.isTrusted)
        // user clicked on the btn 
    else
        // triggered by code
};
```