# How to check if mouse click event is simulated or is native? (non-jQuery way)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

With jQuery it's easy. With pure JavaScript isn't, at least it isn't easy to find out how. `if (event.clientX && event.clientY) { ... }` gives kind-of detection, but it's not 100% accurate.

Comment: Can you describe the situations where it's not accurate? Only real mouse clicks will have those two properties; programmatic clicks should not.

Comment: Yes, they should not, but you still *can simulate* it: `new MouseEvent('click').initMouseEvent('click', false, false, null, null, 0, 0, 200, 200,false, false, false, false, 0, document);` Note `200, 200` args.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov depends what you want to do. for newer browsers you could think over replacing the `Element.prototype.dispatchEvent` function with your own function that adds a property to the event marking it as simulated event, and then passing the event to the original function.

Comment: @t.niese Whoops, sorry, I've started to write my answer before loading your comment. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a way, but it's quite controversial IMHO. Try this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchEvent = (function(dispev) {
    return function(event) {
        // Do your stuff
        dispev.call(this, event);
    };
})(HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchEvent);
```

With this, you're able to catch every call to `dispatchEvent` when a programmatically generated event is dispatched. Of course, this would slow down a bit the dispatching, but shouldn't be a problem unless you're trying to fire *a lot* of events.

In IE8 you must replace `Element.prototype.fireEvent` instead, while in IE7 and lower it's just not possible to do anything about it.

Comment: Whatta circus. But, web always was about that. Thanks for the trick.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794380/detect-if-button-click-real-user-or-triggered-by-a-script see dagg's code to bypass any check.

Comment: @VipinJain And why has that led you to downvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

[Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) can be used upto a satisfactory level.