# Can a website tell if you are using an Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if a website can tell if an Google Chrome extension is used to auto-click on links and filling forms?

I know sometimes it is possible like for AdBlock, because it block content to be loaded. But what if the extension does the same as what a normal user would do?

I hope this question is not too vague?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some hacking methods like [this](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html). However, there is a new protection for extensions, [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources), this restrict the files that can be used on context of a web page.

But this hacking method may still works if there is at least one `web_accessible_resource`

Let's say you want to detect if user is using AdBlock extension.

Unique ID of AdBlock is `gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom`

If you look into manifest.json file of AdBlock extension ([where are the extension files stored?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/6EVtjeaWObs/NEn9ewWizR8J)), you will see there `img/icon24.png` is the one of the web_accessible_resource.

So if you run this code on your website, you can still detect if user is using AdBlock.

```
var detect = function(url, if_installed, if_not_installed) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.onerror = if_not_installed;
    s.onload = if_installed;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    s.src = url;
}
detect('chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/img/icon24.png', function() {alert("yes, this user has AdBlock");});
```

Comment: Thx. I did not know this technique. So there is no was to detect a javascript .click() from a real click?
Edit: Oh I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794380/detect-if-button-click-real-user-or-triggered-by-a-script