# Is there a way to determine if a JS event was fired programmatically or by an actual interaction?

Tags: javascript, events

Say I programmatically set focus on a `textarea` with a simple `document.getElementById('myTextArea').focus();`. On that `textarea` I have an `onFocus` event:

```
document.getElementsByName('myTextArea')[0].onFocus = function () {
    alert('I’m focused!');
};
```

I only want that `onFocus` to be fired when the user actually focuses on the `textarea` and not when I set focus programmatically.

Is there a way in the `onFocus` to tell if the event was triggered by code or by a human, without passing in a parameter of my own?

Comment: Why it is so necessary for you to set focus programmatically when you don't want to do that?

Comment: @Ankit — This is an oversimplified example for the sake of illustrating my need.

Comment: try checking if the hover and focus events are true? Just throwing it out there.

Comment: I believe the answer is no. The only thing I can think of, in your example, is to override the `prototype` for the  `focus` function to set some kind of flag on the DOM element that you check in your event handler. Then you know `focus()` was called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect synthetic clicks on a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442497/detect-synthetic-clicks-on-a-webpage)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher — That ticket is another case of someone-asked-a-javascript-question-and-got-a-jquery-answer. The questions are definitely the same, though.

Comment: @BrandonDurham - That is true, but there is a discussion of regular JavaScript as well.

Comment: Agreed. Happy to have this one closed as a dupe.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when is triggered by the browser it produces an 'originalEvent'.

Comment: I think you’re thinking of jQuery, not JavaScript…

Comment: That's true @BrandonDurham. That was the only way I've found to solve it.