# Js Button Click Alternative

Tags: javascript, buttonclick, alt

I'm building a bot with javascript. I follow my accounts on a platform. I follow by clicking, but the platform understands this and deletes the follower. I'm looking for an alternative way to button click. The site detects the following codes and deletes the follower. Can anyone help?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click();
('#button').trigger('click');
```

This type of button clicks can be detected by the sites. I'm looking for an undetected alternative.

Comment: You can try to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794774/9776840).

Comment: I've tried. I'm waiting for results. There is also the possibility of detection. I hope it works.