# Is it possible to differentiate between a button click triggered by a mouse click and a click triggered by the user's javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Given a button reference, you can use javascript on your console to `.click()` it.

Is there a way for my website to differentiate between a click triggered by a mouse and a click triggered by the user's javascript? Or are these effectively equivalent from the browser's point of view?

Comment: [The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yeah, that's what I want to differentiate from if at all possible.

Comment: Obviously not :) If it simulates the mouse click it does it 100%

Comment: You cannot differentiate in the click handler itself. But you **can** check for mouse position movement beforehand. JavaScript typically doesn't move the mouse pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if button click real user or triggered by a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794380/detect-if-button-click-real-user-or-triggered-by-a-script)

Comment: In which case / element you will recognise if the user is clicked by mouse or press enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Event.isTrusted**

Yes, you can use the `event.isTrusted` property. Will be true when the user clicks as shown in this code snippet.

```js
mybutton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log( "isTrusted = " + e.isTrusted );
});

test.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  mybutton.click();

});
```

```html
<button id="mybutton">My Button</button>

<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Might be noted that click events fired from other means than a mouse will also have it set to true (e.g if you press the Enter key of your keyboard while focusing the button). Also, this property is [[LegacyUnforgeable\]](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#LegacyUnforgeable), so it can't be tampered by code.