# jquery - How can I differentiate user action and action by the script in html body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below jquery code to identify user actions on html page.
This is getting triggered for user action on the page or due to script doing the click . How can I differentiate user action and action by the script?

User action is for example user click on the body . 
script action is, programatically doing onclick on some element of the page or just simple click on the html page .

```
$('body').click(function() {
        console.log(new Date($.now()) + " :: " + "Body Click");
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: User action is ..user click on the body . script action - programatically doing onclick on some element of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [closely related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674669/in-jquery-how-can-i-tell-between-a-programmatic-and-user-click). The short version is you can find out by looking at the event object for things like clientX, clientY, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter event

if **e.which==undefined** means action by script